# Let eclipse open surefire reports automatically

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

When I want to run my JUnit tests in Eclipse (Maven project), I can launch them by "Run as > JUnit test" (1) or by "Run as > Maven test" (2).

In the first case, I get the results visually in the eclipse JUnit View, but the resource files are not copied into `target`, which is bad if I am adjusting the resources while running a test over and over.

In the second case, the resources get copied, but the result is just text at the console or when I open single surefire reports with the eclipse JUnit View.

How can I run "Maven test" from eclipse with automatically opening the generated reports in the JUnit view?

Comment: What do you mean by `but the resource files are not copied into target`? If you run your tests via Eclipse the report is simply given in Eclipse...and it is not neccessary to run the tests via `mvn test`?

Comment: My unit tests use files from `src/test/resources`. When I do a `maven clean` and try to run the tests with (1), the files cannot be found; if I run `maven test` or `maven compile` beforewards and try it again, they can be found.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention @khmarbaise in the previous comment.